# I'm having Issues with flutter_local_notifications. How do i fix this problem?

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have tried the code below and it seems there's something more I need to do. I'm using flutter_local_notification. Do I need to include firebase. Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationApi {
static final _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
static Future _notificationDetails() async {
return NotificationDetails(
  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'com.example.gym',
    'goal_channel',
    importance: Importance.max,
  ),
  iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
);
}

static Future showNotification({
  int id = 0,
  String? title,
  body,
  payload,
 }) async =>
  _notifications.show(
    id,
    title,
    body,
    await _notificationDetails(),
    payload: payload,
  );
}
```

and here's the result
[image: And here's the result]

Comment: add icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher', in AndroidNotificationDetails and retry

Comment: you are a genius! it's amazing how just the Icon delayed me for hours. Thank you, bro

Comment: Anytime bro, Same error happened to me before :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Amroun

Here's a working code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
import'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationApi {
 static final _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
 static Future _notificationDetails() async {
 return NotificationDetails(
  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
  'com.example.gym',
  'goal_channel',
  icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
  importance: Importance.max,
),
iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
);
}

 static Future showNotification({
  int id = 0,
  String? title,
  body,
  payload,
 }) async =>
_notifications.show(
id,
title,
body,
await _notificationDetails(),
payload: payload,
);
}
```